# Removing User from Single User Mode Fails - MacOS 10.14

Tags: terminal, mojave, user-account, error, single-user

So I’m trying to delete a specific user account while avoiding the traditional SysPrefs method. I do have FileVault enabled and am running 10.14.
This is what I’ve tried in Single User mode:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
sudo dscl . delete /Users/username
```

This gives me the errors:

```
Could not read path = /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist, error = 2: No such file or directory
No task-access server configured! The system will not get very far.
```

When I try the dscl command in Recovery Mode I get the DS error -14009. Any clue as to why this is?

Comment: Does it help if you run `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist` after mounting?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Since com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist was giving me issues I ran

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
```

Before executing the dscl delete command which was successful.